# Chrome Extension Database Storage

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am working on a page action extension and would like to store information that all users of the extension can access. The information will be key:value pairs, where the key is a web url and the value is an array of links.

I have to be able to update the database without redeploying the extension to the chrome store. What is it that I should look into using? The storage APIs seem oriented towards user data rather than data stored by the app and updated by the developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something to be updated without deploying an updated version through CWS, you'll need to host the data yourself somewhere and have the extension query it.

Using `chrome.storage.local` as a cache for said data would be totally appropriate.

Comment: What would using chrome.storage.local as a cache accomplish?

Comment: It's probably prohibitively expensive to query your externally-hosted database every time a value is needed, both in terms of hosting costs and latency/reliability of the get operation. A good strategy is to cache the result locally for, say, half an hour. Alternatively, have a separate query that results the "version" of the database, and update local cache if that changes.

Answer (score 1):

the question is pretty broad so ill give you some ideas Ive done before.

since you say you dont want to republish when the db changes, you need to store the data for the db yourself. this doesnt mean you need to store an actual db, just a way for the extension to get the data.

ideally, you are only adding new pairs. if so, an easy way is to store your pairs in a public google spreadsheet. the extension then remembers the last row synced and uses the row feed to get data incrementally.
there a few tricks to get right the spreadsheet sync. take a look at my github "plus for trello" for a full implementation.
this is a good way to incrementally sync, thou if the db isnt huge you could just host a csv file and get it periodically from the extension.

now that you can get the data into the extension, decide how to store it. chrome.storage.local or indexedDb should be fine thou indexedDb is usually best for later querying more complex things than just a hash table.

Comment: The DB is not large, a hosted csv file would be best. I am wondering how to get the data from the hosted CSV to the extension, and how to store that data in local storage. Can you elaborate on how this is done for a beginner? What are some things I should read up on?

Comment: google how to parse a csv. else use an easier format like json. read about localStorage, chrome.storage, infexedDb and their pro/cons.